# Maven: Non-resolvable import POM from other module

Tags: maven, dependency-management, circular-dependency, multi-module

It is something likes [Maven: Non-resolvable parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612309/maven-non-resolvable-parent-pom) but not the same.

I have a parent pom

```xml
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
</modules>
```

`module1` defines some `dependencies` using `dependencyManagement`

child pom: `module3/pom.xml` trying to import `module1`

```xml
<parent>
    <artifactId>group</artifactId>
    <groupId>parent</groupId>
    <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group</groupId>
      <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
      <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
      <!--
      <systemPath>../module1</systemPath>
      -->
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

If I try to build the parent, it is OK

```sh
mvn validate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:

... ...

[INFO] parent ............................................ SUCCESS [0.128s]
[INFO] module1 ........................................... SUCCESS [0.011s]
[INFO] module2 ........................................... SUCCESS [0.009s]
[INFO] module3 ........................................... SUCCESS [0.009s]
... ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

But if I run the build in child module, it fails

```sh
mvn validate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project group:module3:SNAPSHOT (/path-tp/project/module3/pom.xml) has 5 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find group:module1:pom:SNAPSHOT in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 22, column 19 -> [Help 2]
... ...
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

What I'd tried

- I'd try using `systemPath` but it is not supported for `import` scope.
- I'd try move the `import` scope `dependencies` declaration from `module3` to parent-module, but it failed complaining circular-dependency

How can I build/load the lone sub-module `module3`, or is there any other way to split tons of `dependencyManagement`s to multi sub-module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Modules + Building a Single Specific Module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module)

Comment: @Tunaki thanks for the information, it is worked using command line `mvn -pl module3 -am`, but actually I want to load the sub-module pom from some  other utilities likes "running lifecycle from jetbrains IDEA" / "using ant integration (maven-ant) to load dependencies", there is no better support for those situations. maybe I had to move all `dependencyManagements` to parent pom

Answer (score 0):

When working at parent level, Maven is able to resolve dependencies between the modules.

But if your are working inside module 3, it has no idea of the fact that module1 is a sibling module of the project.

You need to install module 1 first if you want to work inside module 3 directly.

Comment: That's why I try using `systemPath` but found that maven has no support for this type of imports

Comment: @WilliamLeung Go to the root level of your project make a `mvn install`. Afterwards use `mvn -pl ...` never change into the folder...and systemPath will never work....