# Could not resolve unknown-version error in pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am new to maven project. I copied some working maven project and while compiling the code Run As -> Maven Install ..
I am getting the below unknown version error:

> The project com.test.abcprocess:ui-test:[unknown-version] (C:\XYZ\GIT_Eclipse\test\pom.xml) has 1 error
>   [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test.abcprocess:ui-test:[unknown-version]: Failure to find com.test.abcprocess:abc-acceptance-test:pom:4.0-SNAPSHOT in https://xyz.123.com/artifactory/bx-test was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]

Here is a part of the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test.abcprocess</groupId>
        <artifactId>abcprocess-acceptance-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ui-test</artifactId>
    <name>Functional Module :: ui-test - ${project.version}</name>    
    <dependencies>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oneleo.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-support-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please help

Comment: Appears to be duplicate of [Maven: Non-resolvable parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612309/maven-non-resolvable-parent-pom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied a part of the maven project. There should be another project with groupid :: com.test.abcprocess

Copy that project also and the hierarchy of all the parent POMs. That should resolve this issue.