# Non-resolvable parent POM in MAVEN Project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, path

I'm trying to add dependencies to my maven project. I want to add spring boot configuration. but it gives this error in parent tag,

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   io.javabrains.springbootquickstart:course-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure
>   to find
>   org.springframework-boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.2.RELEASE
>   in https://  repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be   reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

I tried with adding relative path to this. But it didn't seem to work out.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.javabrains.springbootquickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Java Brains course API</name>

  <parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework-boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath>../course_api/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
</project>
```

Comment: What's the point of `relativePath` tag in the `parent` tag? Maybe that's because of it?

Comment: no i found it after the error occurs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612309/maven-non-resolvable-parent-pom

Comment: but it didn't solve the error anyway :(

Comment: `relativePath` usage is for addressing parent pom file from your filesystem which is not your usecase. I think it's better to send the error you get when you remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve made a small typo in the configuration of your project’s parent. You have used a `-` rather than a `.`. You have `org.springframework-boot` and it should be `org.springframework.boot`.

Your parent should be the following:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```