# Windows 10 WSL - Maven config

Tags: maven, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to configure Windows Maven and WSL Maven to use the same `.m2/repository` and `settings.xml`?

In my `.bashrc` from WSL I added the `M2_HOME` to use the same installation that Windows 10 use:

.bashrc:

`export M2_HOME=/mnt/c/development/maven`

Windows PATH:

`C:\development\maven`

But when I execute `mvn clean install` on Windows Bash, a .m2 folder is created in ~/.m2 (WSL folder system).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found a possible solution.

I created a symbolic link from `~/.m2` to `/mnt/c/Users/<username/.m2`

Command: `$ ln -s /mnt/c/Users/<username>/.m2 ~/.m2`

Until the moment is working fine.

Comment: This 'works', but the performance is dreadful reading the windows filesystem from the WSL. I get build times of:

* 3s if I build from the command prompt, using a .m2 cache in the windows Filesystem
* 3s if I build from WSL with the .m2 cache in the WSL file system
* 20s if I build from WSL with the above symlink

Comment: WSL and Win are two filesystem and building across filesystem is very very slow. My suggestion is just have 2 copies of .m2, or move everything to WSL.

Comment: Is this correct? I ended up with a .m2 link under the ~/.m2 folder. Shouldn't the command end with `~/` instead of `~/.m2`?

Answer (score 2):

Just an amendment to @Vitor 's response:
When you created the symbolic link once, the next time (e.g. if you specified a wrong directory and want to retry) you cannot create it and you will get `failed to create a symbolic link: file exists` error.

As a workaround when you want to recreate the symbolic link, you can use `$ ln -f -s /mnt/c/Users/<username>/.m2 ~/.m2`

```
[OPTION] 
-f, --force
          remove existing destination files
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it by setting the local repository path in (WSL) *~/.m2/settings.xml*
`<localRepository>/mnt/c/Users/<username>/.m2/repository</localRepository>`

Normal maven build is a bit slow when repository is in windows file system, however, when it comes to spring-boot native compile or build-image (mvn -Pnative native:compile),  it takes lot of time, more than the double as compared to when the local repository is in WSL file system.