# Non resolvable parent POM when create Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've created a maven project by using STS4, but when I created, there was an error in line 5 file pom.xml:

> `Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo2:1.0: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.13 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.13 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org`

Here is my file pom.xml
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>demo2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`

What should i do to solve this problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe a network issue?

Comment: Many solutions are listed here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612309/maven-non-resolvable-parent-pom/75682062

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the **-not-available* file in your local maven repository for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.13.

Look at e.g. ( if your local maven repository is .m2)

```
.m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.13/
```

There could be another artefacts with this problem.

If you have too much of these problems you should delete the whole local maven repository.

Afterwards try your maven build with forced update option  again.

Comment: I've deleted this file, but i still got this error

Comment: Is it the same artifact or another one?

Comment: Use mvn with -U option to force update

Comment: I've followed your advices, but still got the same problem

Comment: Remove <relativePath/> entry

Comment: It's still not worked

Comment: Did you added -U option?

Comment: And check the local repository directory again

Comment: Thank you but it's not worked

Comment: Have you access to URL https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.13/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.13.pom

Comment: There is a notify when I access to this URL : This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Comment: I have the same problem with Docker in a project that didn't change for weeks. It gets stuck "Downloading from central" and then throws the same error you have. Changing DNS didn't help. However, I can run mvn verify just fine, even deleting folder .m2, and it loads the repo.